# GMS Shoal Glassfish 3.1.2 : Can somebody translate me this into english :-)

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I hope it is s.t. harmless because TYPE is INFO but it fills the log files a lot.

```
[#|2013-10-18T09:09:01.256+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|ShoalLogger|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GMS1016: Analyzing new membership snapshot received as part of event: IN_DOUBT_EVENT for member: qisi2 of group: QIS|#]

[#|2013-10-18T09:09:01.256+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|ShoalLogger|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GMS1007: Received FailureSuspectedEvent for member: qisi2 of group: QIS|#]

[#|2013-10-18T09:09:01.256+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|ShoalLogger|_ThreadID=15;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GMS1005: Sending FailureSuspectedSignals to registered Actions. member: qisi2 ...|#]
```

Comment: Yes :-) but what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are messages generated by [Shoal GMS](https://shoal.java.net/) which Glassfish uses as its clustering technology. The messages you have there show that it was expecting node `qisi2` to be a member of the cluster.

As it hasn't received any communication from `qisi2` for some time (not sure how long) it's assuming that node has failed.

If 'qisi2' should be a functioning node in the cluster then you should check your cluster config and communication to that node.